# Implicit vs explicit garbage collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, garbage-collection, profiling

**Background**:

I have created an API and I did profiling for memory usage & process time for each web service using [this guide](https://www.codementor.io/tylerboyd/finding-performance-bottlenecks-in-your-rails-api-du107r9zt) and [memory profiler gem](https://github.com/SamSaffron/memory_profiler).

I created a table to keep all profiling results like this:

```
      Request      | Memory Usage(b) | Retained Memory(b) | Runtime(seconds)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Post Login       | 444318          |   35649            | 1.254
  Post Register    | 232071          |   32673            | 0.611
  Get 10 Users     | 11947286        |   2670333          | 3.456
  Get User By ID   | 834953          |   131300           | 0.834
```

Note: all numbers are the average number of calling the same service 3 consecutive times.

And I read many guides and answers(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523039/how-to-destroy-ruby-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121737/ruby-rails-garbage-collection)) says that Garbage Collector is responsible for releasing memory and we should not explicitly interfere in memory management.

Then I just forced the Garbage Collector to start after each action (for test purpose) by adding the following filter in APIController:

```
after_action :dispose

def dispose
   GC.start
end
```

And I found that Memory usage is reduced too much (more than 70%), retained memory almost same before and runtime is reduced as well.

```
      Request      | Memory Usage(b) | Retained Memory(b) | Runtime(seconds)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Post Login       | 38636           |   34628            | 1.023
  Post Register    | 37746           |   31522            | 0.583
  Get 10 Users     | 2673040         |   2669032          | 2.254
  Get User By ID   | 132281          |   128913           | 0.782
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it good practice to add such filter and what are the side effects?
2. I thought that runtime will be more than before, but it seems less, what can be the reason?

**Update:**

I'm using Ruby 2.3.0 and I've used [gc_tracer gem](https://github.com/ko1/gc_tracer) to monitor heap status because I'm afraid to have [old garbage collection issues highlighted in Ruby 2.0 & 2.1](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production)

> The issue is that the Ruby GC is triggered on total number of objects,
>   and not total amount of used memory

Then to do a stress test, I run the following:

```
while true
  "a" * (1024 ** 2)
end
```

and result is that memory usage does not exceed the following limits ([it was exceeding before and GC wont be triggered](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production)):

```
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
```

So now I'm pretty sure that same `GC` issues of 2.0 & 2.1 don't exist anymore in 2.3, but still getting the following positive results by adding above mentioned filter (`after_action :dispose`):

- Heap memory enhanced by 5% to 10% ([check this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/679451/what-could-cause-rubys-free-heap-slots-to-rapidly-increase))
- General execution time enhanced by 20% to 40% (test done using third party tool *Postman* which consumes my API)

I'm still looking for answers to my two questions above.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated